# How to pass one local string into the middle of another string as a variable? .NET C#

Tags: c#, .net

In the below example, how to change the local QNARESULTHERE.json file with the name of the qnaResult?

```
public async Task ITSupportIntent(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)
{
    var qnaResult = itKB.GetAnswer(result.Query);
    if (qnaResult.StartsWith("CARD"))
    { 
        var reply = context.MakeMessage();            
        try
        {
            string json = File.ReadAllText(HttpContext.Current.Request.MapPath("~\\AdaptiveCards\\QNARESULTHERE.json"));
```

Sorry this question is all over the place.
Context:
The actual variable i needed was the QnAAnswer i believe as referenced here: [Integrate QnA Maker and LUIS to distribute your knowledge base](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/qnamaker/tutorials/integrate-qnamaker-luis#qna-maker--luis-bot)

Comment: Change in what way? Completely replace `QNARESULTHERE` with the content of it the variable?

Comment: You are doing `reply = context.MakeMessage()` and then `reply.Attachments.Add(new Attachment{...})`, is that in any way related to changing the JSON file? If not then please consider taking that out, so we can focus on the actual issue of **what** you want to insert/replace **where** in the JSON file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a little unclear exactly what value you are trying to get from the result, but assuming `LuisResult` has a `FileName` property on it, as an example, you can use string interpolation (available since C# 7), like this:

```
string relativePath = $"~\\AdaptiveCards\\{result.FileName}.json";
```

You may also find that the `@`-style verbatim string syntax works better here, since it means you don't have to escape backslashes:

```
string relativePath = $@"~\AdaptiveCards\{result.FileName}.json";
```

If you're using an older version of C#, you can also use `string.Format` or just plain old string concatenation:

```
string relativePath = string.Format(@"~\AdaptiveCards\{0}.json", result.FileName);
string relativePath = @"~\AdaptiveCards\" + result.FileName + ".json";
```

Whichever you choose, you will of course want to pass the resulting value along like you were doing.

```
string json = File.ReadAllText(HttpContext.Current.Request.MapPath(relativePath));
```

Comment: you can also use @$ to simply further

Answer (score 2):

You can use `string.Format()` like so:

```
string json = File.ReadAllText(HttpContext.Current.Request.MapPath(string.Format(@"~\AdaptiveCards\{0}.json", qnaResult));
```

Above is assuming `qnaResult` is a string that contains the file name you want. If it's a class instance, then use the appropriate property of it that contains the file name.